# How to install cgit on nginx?

Tags: nginx, cgit

I am using following "https://gist.github.com/stran12/1394757" gist to install cgit on nginx. I have almost done with all the steps. My nginx server is also up and running. While starting "cgit-fastcgi" service, i am getting below error:

> Argument "/tmp/cgi.sock" isn't numeric in foreach loop entry at
>   /usr/bin/spawn-fcgi line 22.

Any idea how to fix this error.

My spawn-fcgi file is:

> #!/usr/bin/perl
>
> use strict; use warnings FATAL => qw( all );
>
> use IO::Socket::UNIX;
>
> my $bin_path = '/usr/bin/fcgiwrap';
>
> my $socket_path = $ARGV[0] || '/tmp/cgi.sock';
>
> my $num_children = $ARGV[1](https://gist.github.com/stran12/1394757) || 1;
>
> close STDIN;
>
> unlink $socket_path; my $socket = IO::Socket::UNIX->new(
>       Local => $socket_path,
>       Listen => 100, );
>
> die "Cannot create socket at $socket_path: $!\n" unless $socket;
>
> for (1 .. $num_children) {
>       my $pid = fork;
>       die "Cannot fork: $!" unless defined $pid;
>       next if $pid;
>
> ```
> exec $bin_path;
> die "Failed to exec $bin_path: $!\n"; }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just re-installed `spawn-fcgi` again, following the link

https://github.com/anujsharma12feb/cgit-fcgiwrap-nginx/wiki

and it worked for me.

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install spawn-fcgi